# How to get parameters using "/:params" in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to get parameters from a link similar to this "sample.com/product/45" using "product/:id",
Here is my route declaration :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'product/:id', component: Product }
];
```

Here is the component class

```
export class Product implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  id: number;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id'];

       console.log(this.id); //I get undefined here
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

when i tried to console.log() the id , i got undefined

Comment: do you see the route params?

Comment: yes it keep showing when i visit the link

Comment: no does it come inside ngOnit when you debug?

Comment: no . when i debug i get undefined

Comment: can you try with this code, ngOnInit() {
     this.id  = +this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
}

Comment: it works ! . i tried the following :
ngOnInit() {this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];}

instead of :

this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id'];
    });

please post it  as answer , and i'll accept it.

Comment: posted answer below

Comment: Upvote if it helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params["id"];
}
```